# MS Reporting Services report viewer in MS Access Database

Tags: ms-access, reporting-services

I have a report deployed on a MS Reporting Services server, working fine. I can access it from a ASPX page with no problems, set the report parameters, etc, using the Report Viewer component from Microsoft. Works great.

The question is: is there any way to view this report WITHIN a form in an **Access** database? 
Is there a version of the report viewer that can be used with MS Access?

I have searched online, but I can't find a solution.

I know an Access report can be imported into SSRS, but I need to be able to view an SSRS report from within Access.

Thanks!!

Comment: To manipulate it from within Access, you need a COM interface and if you want to display it within Access, you likely need some kind of ActiveX control that can display the foreign report. Ugly? You bet. But those tools weren't designed to be used in Access, given that Access provides one of the best report writers in existence.

Answer (score 2):

Not in a form directly.

The best you'll get is some kind of "Web" Control that can be used to give an IE session to the report. Or have a link label with URL Access to create a separate IE Window.

Comment: I tried the Web Browser Control and I couldn't get it to work properly. It asks for the password 3 or 4 times ... however it does not display the report in the end. I'd recommend the 2nd approach with an external IE window.

Answer (score 2):

insert, activeX control, Microsoft Web Browser would allow you to setup a web browser control inside of an Access form.

I think that SSRS is a completely superior product, I'd just get rid of Access and use a current reporting tool.  Microsoft has implemented ReportViewer controls that allow you to embed SSRS reports anywhere you want (in .NET land).

Perhaps you could build an Access add-in that uses this control.

But the bottom line is that SSRS is the future-- SSRS is embedded in the middle of dozens of Microsoft software products - Team Foundation Server for example.. and I think that it's obvious that SSRS is more powerful and yet it's still FREE in the express edition.